# Why is WebView's LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN deprecated?

Tags: android, webview

I am wondering why [`LayoutAlgorithm`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.html)`.SINGLE_COLUMN` deprecated? It has use cases where `NARROW_COLUMNS` doesn't do the job:

I have a short HTML snippet that includes an image that is wider than the device screen. `NARROW_COLUMNS` doesn't resize the image to fit the screen, whereas `SINGLE_COLUMN` scales it down so the user cannot scroll horizontally (which is what I want).

Any ideas as to why it is deprecated?

Comment: I have no idea at all honestly. But according to the docs, `NARROW_COLUMNS` should do what `SINGLE_COLUMN` does IF POSSIBLE. Am I mistaken? So, maybe with all this html5 and the rapid changes in web, they decided to stick to the "IF POSSIBLE" option as they can not guarantee it and/or make sure everything works fine when `SINGLE_COLUMN` is enforced.

Comment: Exactly, that is the whole point. "If possible" doesn't make any sense because it certainly is possible using the deprecated `SINGLE_COLUMN`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because they changed the [Webcore.h](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/page/Settings.h) class witch [LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/webkit/WebSettings.java#WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.0SINGLE_COLUMN) is embed to to.

I sugest you to find html layout solution.

Answer (score 0):

`NARROW_COLUMNS` is also deprecated now and you have to use `TEXT_AUTOSIZING` which also doesn't work as expected.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#Columns

Your best option is to find a custom WebView or, if you can, change your HTML.